# Is it possible to group documents by a certain value in an array containing subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection holding a few million documents with a structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "5c94bdbfcfccf91aa6903254",
    "source" : "somesourceinfo/6410",
    "language" : "de-de",
    "date_created" : "2019-03-22T10:10:58",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "SALE",
            "type" : "product.category"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "KOCHEN & BACKEN, Kochen, Bräter / Schmortöpfe",
            "type" : "product.category"
        },
        {
            "value" : "4009209314754",
            "type" : "product.gtin"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "Fissler",
            "type" : "product.manufacturer"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "55122631",
            "type" : "product.manufacturer_number"
        }
     ]
}
```

I need to combine documents that have the same product.gtin into a single document where data is an array that contains the elements of all data arrays of matching documents.

I have tried with the aggregation framework but I always seem to get stuck somewhere. I usually start by matching documents that actually contain a "product.gtin".

I then tried to group by that value (the value property in the respective array element) and combine the "data"-Array by using $addToSet, but either grouping by that value is not possible or I just don't find the right expression to do it.

I also tried to convert the array to an object and place them into the root of the document, but then i ran into problems, because our types have a dot in them, so I cannot access the properties anymore.

I have tried a few other approaches but usually I run into problems at some point.

I am asking myself if this is actually possible to achieve with a datastructure like ours.

Example of how I start:

```
db.bulk.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: { "data.type" : { $eq : "product.gtin" }} 
        }
    ],
    { allowDiskUse : true }
)
```

The next stage would be $group and then use the value of the appropriate array element, but i can not seem to be able to access it. 
I have seen people access subdocuments in arrays via $unwind, but then it seems, that after doing that, I can not really group in a good way (example data.value) without also grouping by other values that are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer because the old one contained a bug:

```
db.bulk.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: { "data.type": { $eq: "product.gtin" } }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                gtin: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$data",
                        initialValue: "",
                        in: { $concat: ["$$value", { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$$this.type", "product.gtin"] }, then: "$$this.value", else: "" } }] }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                data: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$data",
                        as: "el",
                        in: { type: "$$el.value", value: "$$el.value", source: "$source" }
                    }
                },
                source: "$source",
                gtin: "$gtin"
            }
        },

        { $group: { _id: "$gtin", data: { $addToSet: "$data" }, source: { $addToSet: "$source" } } },
        {
            $addFields: {
                data: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$data",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { $out: "bulk.gtin" }
    ],
    { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

1. I use $match, so only documents where a gtin exists are selected.
2. I use $addFIelds to add an gtin field to the root of the document. The field is added by using $reduce, which itereates over the "$data" array and concatenating the value of data.value to the initial value of an empty string, when data.type is "product.gtin". That way I hava a field containing the gtin of the document which i can use for step 3.
3. Using $project and $map I add the document_id to each element in the "$data"-Array. That way it is easy to know where each element came from. Also (important for our use-case) this way, each "$data"-array is different. When using $addToSet in the next step, arrays containing the exact same documents would not be added together. But we want duplicates so we can count them later on. This way every "$data"-array is actually differenct, because it contains different _ids and is definitely added to the set.
4. I then use $group to group the documents by the newly created "$gtin" field. I also add the values from "$data" and "$source" to arrays via $addToSet.
5. I use add field to overwrite the $data field. In step 3, $addInSet did not add the actual array elements one by one, but the whole array contained in "$data". 
   So I have to make one single array out of the several arrays that are currently in "$data". 
   I use reduce for this, which takes the elements, contained in $data and just concatenates them together. This way I also keep duplicate elements, which is what I intended.
6. Lastly I write the output to a new collection